# jQuery: How can you test for the *absence* of a class?

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

Given that this is the correct way to see if 'this' has class 'selected':

```
if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
   // logic goes here
}
```

What is the correct way to test for the **absence** of a class?

That is, how can I test if 'this' does *not* have class 'selected'?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
if (!$(this).hasClass('selected')) {
    // logic goes here
}
```